# Wrong Module gets loaded through lazy loading

Tags: typescript, angular5, angular-routing

This is my app-routing structure:

```
export const AppRoutes: Routes = [
{
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'project',
    pathMatch: 'full',
}, {
    path: '',
    component: AdminLayoutComponent, canActivate: [Authguard],
    children: [
        {
            path: 'project',
            loadChildren: 'app/projectTable/projectTable.module#ProjectTableModule'
        },
        {
            path: 'wizard',
            loadChildren: 'app/wizard/wizard.module#WizardModule'
        },
        {
            path: 'workflows',
            loadChildren: 'app/workflows/workflows.module#WorkflowsModule'
        },
        {
            path: 'setup',
            loadChildren: 'app/setup/setup.module#SetupModule'
        }
    ]
},
{
    path: '',
    component: AuthLayoutComponent, canActivate: [Anonguard],
    children: [{
        path: 'login',
        loadChildren: './pages/pages.module#PagesModule'
    }]
}
];
```

Whenever I click setup tab, the projectTable module gets loaded. I don't know what I am doing wrong here. Forgive me if the answer is obvious as i'm still a beginner in angular.
The image shows 2 routes being loaded for setup module.

[image]

Comment: Have you imported ProjectTableModule into your  SetupModule import section?

Comment: The parent route specifies `redirectTo: 'project'`. That's why

Comment: Yes I was because I needed to access a service from that module. Removing the import did the trick. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Just for an suggestion you are mentioning your route. **Default path for project** then only it navigate project module that's the problem.

```
{
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'project', //here you mentioned if path empty go to project
    pathMatch: 'full',
},
```

i believe what you have mistake in your code.

If you provide what url you are trying to navigate **SetupModule**.I mean **'/setup'** or something else?

Also provide SetupModule code.